# Azure Mobile Services in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, azure, azure-mobile-services

How can I implement my Windows Azure Mobile Services in an HTML page??

I tried the code snippets that are present in the Azure portal but it just didn't work..

The code snippets that they ask me to put in my HTML page are:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.2.5.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("key1", "key2");
```

Then when I try to insert a record into the database I use this code:

```
var get_table = client.getTable("People");
get_table.insert({ FirstName: "Marwan", LastName: "Younis" });
```

Comment: Which parts didn't work? Links to code snippets?

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried.

Comment: I added the code snippets to my description of the problem, kindly check them above. Thank you!

Comment: can you include what error you are getting?  Its not clear what is not working from your question

Comment: the error is that it is not inserting any data into the database, and the error is "Bad Request"

Answer (score 0):

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("key1", "key2");
```

Did you replace key1 to your service URL? If you testing on your published service, it should be [servicename].azure-mobile.net, local debug should be http://localhost:51029

key2 should be your app key which you can get it from your azure portal > mobile service instance > manage key.